# A circle separating the critical points

Tags: cv.complex-variables

A circle $C$ is said to be a separating circle for a set $S=\{z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n\}$ if either there are points from $S$ in the interior and the exterior of the circle $C$ or all points of $S$ are on $C.$  Can we find a circle which separates the critical points of a given polynomial using information on its zeros?  It is an open question I am working on.

Comment: You should also explain what you have tried, what progress you have made so far.

Comment: Does "information on its zeros" include both their locations and multiplicities?  If you know that, you know the polynomial up to a constant factor, so of course you can determine the critical points.

Comment: Sounds like the famed Gauss-Lucas theorem might come in handy here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem

Comment: In some instances, you can use Walsh's Two Circle Theorem.